# Xiling ise installation on ubuntu

Tags: xilinx

Is there command can be given in terminal to install xilinxs ise 14.7 software on ubuntu 22.04. From xilinx website we get the file to be downloaded for full linux installation. But how to do all downloading and installation by terminal. Please help what command to be given to run xilinx 14.7 ise software.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Did you try following the installation instructions for Ubuntu at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meO-b6Ib17Y (click the **...more** option to show the installation instructions)? What happens if you follow these installation instructions?